# Connect to socket on form submit node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to io.connect() on form submit for that I had coded like below

```
var socket;

$('#registration').submit(function(e)
{
    socket = io.connect();
}); 

socket.on('newuser', function(data)
{ 
    // getting error as "cannot read property on of undefined"
});
```

Is this correct way to connect to socket on some front end actions(like form submit).
I think due to that only I am getting error as "cannot read property on of undefined".
Please direct me to correct way.

Comment: at the point you're calling `.on`, `socket` hasn't been assigned a value.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I set setTimeout at server side even though it is not working.

Comment: That makes no sense. The code that you have presented is all client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got a simple solution

```
      var socket;

     $('#registration').submit(function(e)
     {
       socket = io.connect();
       run_socket();
     }); 


   function run_socket(){

    socket.on('newuser', function(data){

      // getting error as "cannot read property on of undefined"
    });

   }
```